# Is there an ambiguity in translation of Frege's "Bestande des Gedankens"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

The phrase "Bestande des Gedankens" is differently translated as (A) "the make-up of a thought" or (B) "the being of a thought" in the context of the following passage:

> Wir können durch unser Urteilen am Bestande des Gedankens nichts ändern. Wir können nur anerkennen, was ist. Einem wahren Gedanken können wir durch unser Urteilen nichts anhaben. Wir können in dem ihn ausgedrückenden Satze ein "nicht" einfügen und dadurch einen Satz erhalten, der, wie dargelegt worden ist, keinen Ungedanken enthält, sondern als Bedingungssatz oder Folgesatz in einem hypotetischen Satzgefüge seine volle Berechtingung haben kann. Weil er falsch ist, darf er nur nicht mit behauptender Kraft ausgesprochen werden. Jener erste Gedanke aber wird durch diesen Vorgang ganz unberührt gelassen. Er bleibt wahr wie vorher.

(It's from Gottlob Frege's 1918 manuscript "Die Verneinung"). Cassell's dictionary from 1906, however, does not mention any meaning of "Bestand" similar to "make-up" any other noun that would indicate some structural features.

My question is: Is the (A) translation simply mistaken, or there is some turn of phrase that justifies it?

Comment: From a literal viewpoint, yes, (b) is a "wrong" translation. But considering a *thought* can never be a static thing, but rather is a temporary action, "make-up" can't be that wrong.

Comment: It is impossible to talk seriously about a single sentence in a philosophical essay without knowing the text as a whole. You should at least provide a full paragraph.

Comment: @tofro Thanks for the comment, but Fregean "thoughts" are not thoughts informally conceived; they are not actions, but rather objective contents which can be grasped and judged.

Comment: @Olafant I included it in the edit.

Comment: Translation A seems to have interpreted *Bestand* in the sense of *bestehen aus* "consist of", a meaning which the noun doesn't have.

Answer (score 4):

You don't provide a reference to translation a), which I would consider as wrong.

Actually [Bestand](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bestand) reflects a very stable state (compare the phrase *Bestand haben*,) while *make-up* would probably be phrased as *Vorstellung*, *Unterstellung*, *Hypothese* or similar.

I find *being* as translation also a bit weak, because it does not contribute much to the aspect of persistence. In the restricted context given I  would translate Frege's sentence as:

> We can't change existence/persistence of the thought by our judgement.

Comment: Thanks - that stands in line with Cassell! Translation is (A) is by Peter Geach, and it's the only published English translation of "Die Verneinung" from "Collected Papers" [1984], Brian McGuinness (ed.) (also reprinted in "The Frege Reader" [1997], Michael Beaney (ed.)). Translation (B) is from Mark Textor's paper "Frege on Judging as Acknowledging the Truth” in Mind 119 (475).

Comment: *Make-up* would be *Zusammensetzung*.